# How can I disable the Snipping Tool functionality triggered by the Print Screen key in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, snipping-tool

I recently upgraded to Windows 11 and noticed that the Print Screen key now opens the Snipping Tool instead of taking a screenshot and copying it to the clipboard as it did in previous versions of Windows. While I appreciate the Snipping Tool's capabilities, I prefer the old behavior of capturing the entire screen directly to the clipboard.

Is there a way to disable the Snipping Tool functionality assigned to the Print Screen key in Windows 11? I would like to restore the traditional functionality where pressing Print Screen automatically captures the screen and copies it to the clipboard without opening any additional tools.

I have tried exploring the Windows settings and control panel, but I couldn't find an option to revert this key's behavior. Any suggestions or alternative methods to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, very frustrating that Microsoft constantly seem to be breaking stuff that's worked fine for years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change this feature in Accessibility Settings.

[Change PrtScr in Snipping Tool](https://www.techspot.com/news/98269-microsoft-set-change-print-screen-button-opens-snipping.html#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20has%2C%20however%2C%20included%20a,changed%20by%20editing%20the%20registry.)

> Despite the Snipping Tool's various features, many people, this writer
> included, would rather keep the Print Screen button's original
> function. Microsoft has, however, included a way to revert this change
> by going to the Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard menu and toggling
> the 'Use the Print Screen key to open Snipping Tool' to off. It can
> also be changed by editing the registry.

I have the most recent version of Windows 11 Pro and tested to ensure this works.

Answer (score 2):

As [@John](https://superuser.com/a/1786602/432339) mentioned, it can also be disabled with a registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"PrintScreenKeyForSnippingEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quick Fix in the Windows Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ9oT.jpg) *(Screenshots with Steps)*

Best Regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just my two cents: this was the best answer.  All the information is in a very clear screenshot. The selected answer is more time consuming and not as direct of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing as "Settings -> Accessibility...
Cab someone provide what of the choices presented might lead us to the right path?

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242066)